# Calculate parameters of active high pass and low pass filter given for EOG circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, active-filter, biopotential

[image]

The circuit is from [here.](https://www.mdpi.com/2079-9292/9/6/970)

The opamps are : OPA2335 (dual channel because of horizontal and vertical electrodes.)

I don't exactly understand how to calculate R and C values based on the 0.5 high pass and 35Hz low pass in these configurations. I'd know how to do it for passive circuits but this just confuses me and the datasheets don't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I don't exactly understand how to calculate R and C values based on
> the 0.5 high pass and 35Hz low pass based on these configurations. I'd
> know how to do it for passive circuits but this just confuses me and
> the datasheets don't help either.*

The CR high-pass filter uses an op-amp buffer following it. That buffer does nothing but provide unity gain i.e. it doesn't affect the CR high-pass response and, on its output, it faithfully reproduces the signal from the CR network.

The next stage is a Sallen Key 2nd-order unity-gain low pass filter. There are literally hundreds of web resources on this type of circuit but, the only thing that is unclear from the diagram is the Q factor. You need this to estimate the resistor and capacitor values but, from experience, I would expect Q to be between 0.5 and 0.8.

Try this Sallen key calculator: http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPseikiLowkeisan.htm

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do I calculate the R & C values, does any pair work, or is the selection dependent on other factors?

Comment: Any idea what the purpose of the two potentiometers are for the second amplifier and the R & C values for the active feedback circuit?

Comment: @Roshan use the link in the answer and play around with values and, if you scroll down the link the site produces bode plots for each run you perform. Generally, try and keep resistor values between 1 kohm and 1 Mohm. Keep capacitor values above 10 pF and below 10 uF as a general rule.

Comment: I believe those potentiometers adjust signal gain and DC offset. You might want to raise a new question for the R and C you talk about. I have half an idea but not really enough and, other folk's answers might be revealing.

Comment: @Roshan if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: I've used bode plots for stability, unsure how to use the plots to help design the R C values, can you please elucidate.

Comment: Also, based on what are is the ranges of resistor and capacitance values that you have mentioned as acceptable?

Comment: I would advise you to just watch how the bode plot changes when you alter the resistor and capacitor values. If you don't understand what the bode plot is telling you, it is a big subject to grasp and is better suited to a new formal question @Roshan

Comment: Maybe try 100 kohm for the resistors, 33 nF for C1 and 10 nF for C2 then look at the bode plot!!